# Remote keyboard input C/C++

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, client-server

I've got client-C# application. It sends mouse/keyboard input to server side, like this

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    code = (int)e.KeyCode;
    //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("code:{0}", coordX));
    command_flag = (int)command.PRESS_BUTTON;
}
```

And when the server, written using C and win32, receives  command to press button it calls this procedure:

```
void PressButton(int buttonCode)
{
    INPUT Input = { 0 };
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki.wVk = buttonCode;
    Input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    //Input.ki.wScan = 0;
    Input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    //wchar_t message[512];
    //wsprintf(message, L"butt :%d", buttonCode);
    //MessageBox(NULL, message, NULL, MB_OK);

    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    Input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));

}
```

But at target machine all the inputs is made in current machine's keyboard layout, not mine. If i use english layout and pressing keys on form, and server-side machine has russian layout, input is in russian. How can I set client-side layout for being sending to server? Thats my first experience in client-server applications, so I would be glad to advices. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, this might be quite a job. Firstly, is the client running on a different machine?  What connections are there between the client and the server? At the very least you would need to write some sort of message system that would then need to be broadcasted over what ever connection you have available - serial, USB, bluetooth, network etc. The client and server would need listeners that would receieve the message and then handle it accordingly.  So, you press a key on client machine, client sends this message to the server, it receives and then handles the message.

Comment: Yes, I have already have that code. I 'am sending packets with commands (GET_SCREE, PRESS_BUTTON, CLICK_MOUSE) and additional data (coordX, coordY or button code) and server then look into incoming packets and executea appropriate functions. So from c# app now I'am sending command PRESS_BUTTON and button code to C/Winapi server, button code is received but input is made in server's keyboard layout, not clients. Also, I've noticed, that shift doesn't work to. But I need to handle it and some key combinations like Ctrl+, Alt+.

Comment: Handling both shift keys (plus ALT and CTRL) would be done reading to the scan codes and of course handling the down/pressed states of the keys. From when I last did this, I basically coded all states and produced the proper ascii code as well. There are a heap of websites that explain this and whole process of how the client and server work.

Comment: Neither client nor server are Unicode aware. The client simply butchers the [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration (ignoring semantics) into something that could be a virtual key code (but isn't). And the server picks up the mess and passes it on to the system. `SendInput` doesn't care about keyboard layouts. But you have to feed it correct information. (And stop using `1` as the first parameter to `SendInput`. The API was introduced to fix the very issue you are introducing by passing `1`. What irony.)

Comment: @IInspectable I see, how to find out correct information that I should pass to SendInput? And what's wrong with 1 as first parameter?

Comment: What's wrong with 1 as first param? You'd know if you'd read the docs properly.